# Non annotation argument to lifecycle method with descriptor

Tags: osgi

I am adding Maven build capability to an existing OSGI 7 project.  It builds just fine with bnd within Eclipse, and with Gradle.  But I am getting the following error when building with Maven:

```
[ERROR] /Users/randy/projects/xyz/src/com.xyz.masterdata/com.xyz.masterdata.core.logic.provider/bnd.bnd [0:0]: Non annotation argument to lifecycle method with descriptor (Lorg/osgi/service/transaction/control/TransactionControl;Lorg/osgi/service/transaction/control/jdbc/JDBCConnectionProvider;)V,  type org/osgi/service/transaction/control/TransactionControl
[ERROR] /Users/randy/projects/xyz/src/com.xyz.masterdata/com.xyz.masterdata.core.logic.provider/bnd.bnd [0:0]: Non annotation argument to lifecycle method with descriptor (Lorg/osgi/service/transaction/control/TransactionControl;Lorg/osgi/service/transaction/control/jdbc/JDBCConnectionProvider;)V,  type org/osgi/service/transaction/control/jdbc/JDBCConnectionProvider
```

The offending code is as follows, specifically the constructor method with the @Activate annotation:

```
@Component(property = {
                "provider.target=(databaseName=MasterData)"
        })
public class ConsumerChannelDaoImpl implements ConsumerChannelDao
{
    private final TransactionControl _transactionControl;
    private Connection _connection;

    @Activate
    public ConsumerChannelDaoImpl(@Reference TransactionControl txControl, @Reference(name = "provider") JDBCConnectionProvider provider)
    {
        _transactionControl = txControl;
        _connection = provider.getResource(txControl);
    }
```

My pom.xml has the following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>osgi.annotation</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>osgi.cmpn</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.service.http.whiteboard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.service.jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.service.jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    ....
</dependencies>
```

I'm at a loss as to what is causing this issue.  Some thoughts on how to resolve when building an OSGi 7 project with Maven is appreciated.

Thanks,
Randy

Comment: You do not mention what version of Bnd you are using for the maven plugins. It is possible you are using an older version of Bnd which does not support constructor injection.

Comment: That did the trick... updated bnd-maven-plugin to 4.3.1, and it worked like a charm.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BJ Hargrave had pointed out I was using an older version of bnd-maven-plugin.  Updating to v4.3.1 did the trick.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>biz.aQute.bnd</groupId>
            <artifactId>bnd-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-bnd-process</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bnd-process</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```